Movie about terrorist planing to nuke a city with a small atomic bomb
I try to find a movie I have seen in the 80s, which begins with this plot:
A nuke explodes in the desert (maybe Nevada). The military denies that they have tested one. Two journalists interviews a old man at a farm who has witnessed the explosions and now shows symptoms of radioactive exposure (using a Geiger tube they prove that it is indeed radioactivity). 
After a while the journalists find out that the terrorists plan to place a second bomb in a building in the center of a city (big one like San Francisco) and to blackmail the government. In the end they find the bomb and defuse it.
Does anyone know the title of the movie?

"Deadline" (1982)
IMDb:

A journalist sets out to report on a minor earthquake in the Australian outback, and finds that the tremor was a result of a small nuclear explosion - part of an extortion threat that has the government fearing nuclear blackmail. With the help of local reporters, and despite the harassment of the security agencies, he sets out to avert the crisis.
The film opens effectively, with peaceful footage of the western New South Wales Outback's fauna, soon distressed by an enormous explosion that produces a type of mushroom cloud. As Canberra authorities are puzzling over what might be an earthquake, a ransom demand for cash and narcotics is received by the National Security Adviser, proxy for the Prime Minister in this instance since there is no apparent military involvement with the threat. At this time, an American journalist, Barney Duncan (Barry Newman) determines that there was indeed a nuclear blast in the Outback and he, with an obligatory comely female companion, Gillian, played by Trisha Noble, discover that a second nuclear bomb has been planted in Sydney, with fewer than 48 hours before its programmed detonation.

Here is a clip, it starts with the old dude witnessing the nuclear explosion in the desert, and later you can see the terrorists planting the second device in the city:
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xcmnjq_deadline_shortfilms

Thank you! Finally someone could tell me the name ... I was searching for so long, but could not find it anywhere.
